# Relation between convex functions

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I formed the following conjecture and, since I can't find counterexamples, am trying to prove it.

> Let $f, g :[0,x_{max}]\rightarrow {\mathbb R}^{+}$ such that
>
> - $f',g'>0$
> - $f'',g''>0$
> - $f(x) > g(x)$
> - $f(x_{max})$ = $g(x_{max})$ and $f(0)$ = $g(0)$.
>
> Then $\int_0^{x_{max}} (f'(x))^2 < \int_0^{x_{max}} (g'(x))^2$.

Is this true and, if so, how can I prove it?

PS: We found this relation between the integral of the squared derivatives while playing with statistics. In fact, this relation is equivalent to a relation between the standard deviations $\sigma_{f'}>\sigma_{g'}$.

Thanks for your help!

Edit: small typo in equation

Comment: I'm not sure, what the question is? Do you want to see a formal proof for you hypothesis or do you want an example or..?

Comment: If it is a simple proof then you can tell me it. Of course you can also tell me what, in your opinion, could be an hint to demonstrate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I would replace all the $>$ with $\ge$, else th fourth,e third and second to last conditions are contradictory.

That said the statement is true, and can be proven by partial integration:
$$\begin{array}{ll}\int_0^{x_0}f'(x)^2-g'(x)^2dx&=\int_0^{x_0}(f'+g')(f'-g')dx\\&=\underbrace{\bigg[(f'+g')(f-g)\bigg]_0^{x_0}}_{=0}-\int_0^{x_0}\underbrace{(f''+g'')}_{\ge0}\underbrace{(f-g)}_{\ge0}dx\end{array}$$
And thus:
$$\int_0^{x_0}f'(x)^2-g'(x)^2dx\le0$$
Notice that the assumptions we have used are:

1. $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$
2. $f(x)\ge g(x)$ for all $x$
3. $f''(x)+g''(x)\ge0$ for all $x$

Thus we only need that one function dominates the other, that they agree on the boundary and that the **sum** of the functions is convex.

Comment: Thanks for the elegant demonstration! I wouldn't be able to find it!